# SMARTY > Nested foreach loop > Overall counter

Tags: foreach, nested, smarty, iteration, counter

I have a nested smarty foreach loop.
I am trying to get sequentially numbered output on the divs *( see example )*
Using the key or index or .iteration on the inner array doesn't work the way I want.
I can see what's happening, but I want some way of keeping an overall running count, rather than a partial count, that keeps resetting on every branch of the outer loop.
I have tried numerous things without success.
Can anyone help ? Much appreciated.

```
{foreach from=$children item='child'}

{if $child.show_in_menu}


{* loop through grandchildren *}

{foreach from=$child item='grandchild'  name='grandchildrenpages' key=k}

{if $grandchild.show_in_menu}


<div class="view-{$k}"></div>

{/if}
{/if}
{/foreach}
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

**Desired output**

```
<div class="view-1"></div>
<div class="view-2"></div>
<div class="view-3"></div>
<div class="view-4"></div>
<div class="view-5"></div>
<div class="view-6"></div>
<div class="view-7"></div>
<div class="view-8"></div>
```

**Currentoutput**

```
<div class="view-0"></div>
<div class="view-1"></div>
<div class="view-2"></div>
<div class="view-1"></div>
<div class="view-2"></div>
<div class="view-5"></div>
<div class="view-6"></div>
<div class="view-7"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use {counter}:

```
{foreach from=$children item='child'}
        {if $child.show_in_menu}
    {foreach from=$child item='grandchild'  name='grandchildrenpages' key=k}
                {if $grandchild.show_in_menu}
        <div class="view-{counter}"></div>
                {/if}
    {/foreach}
        {/if}
{/foreach}
```

(btw, your example has one {/if} more than needed, I guess it's a typo

Comment: Thanks periklis, I'm slightly embarrassed by the simplicity of the solution ! I did try and implement a {counter} in an attempt to resolve this, but erroneously set up the counter outside of the loop , assigned a variable to it ad tried to call it inside. Basically I misunderstood how to use it. The extra {/if} was left in by mistake, sorry, I tried to get all the unnecessary specifics out of the real life code, to avoid confusion, but unfortunately left this in. Thanks again - most helpful.